# Submit Button that is in a Javascript using Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I cannot seem to submit the click the submit or go button.  It seems to be under a javascript which I am not sure how to enter a code to click the go button.   Here is what I have:

```
Sub FactFinderForm()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'create new instance of IE. use reference to return current open IE if
'you want to use open IE window. Easiest way I know of is via title bar.
IE.Navigate "http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml###"
'go to web page listed inside quotes
IE.Visible = True

While IE.busy
DoEvents 'wait until IE is done loading page.
Wend

IE.Document.getElementsByname("cfsearchtextboxmain").Item.innertext = _
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1")

While IE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

SendKeys "{enter}"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With IE.Document

    .getElementById("cfsearchtextboxmain").Value = _
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Value

    .parentWindow.ExecScript "cfMainFormSubmit()"

End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also have used a css selector to target the element.

```
#cfmainsearchform > a
```

That says `a` tag within element with id `cfmainsearchform`.  `#` is id and `>` within ([child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)).

```
ie.document.querySelector("#cfmainsearchform > a").Click
```